# Is there a simple way to specify whether a webp is lossy (like jpg), lossless (like png), or animated (like a gif)?

Tags: images, filenames, file-extension, webp

For example, is it possible to name something "file.lwebp" to explicitly designate that it is lossy, or "file.awebp" to designate it is animated? Or is there no such method, and you just have to explicitly check the file?

Comment: You can name any file any way you want. Please provide more context.

Comment: @DanielB For example, .ogg is a great file format, but can contain lots of different things. ".oga" makes you know explicitly that you're working with audio, ".ogv" lets you know you're working with video data, and ".ogx" lets you know its multiplexed data. I'm wondering if webp has a similar thing to let someone know whether the data is lossy (like jpg), lossless (like png), or animated (like gif).

Comment: That’s already in your question, yes. However, what is the context? Your local file archive? File associations in Windows? Files on the internet a browser would navigate to? Files that you send to someone else?

Answer (score 0):

Naming the file with a different extension will have no effect on its contents.

Specifically, adding or removing characters from the file's extension will not change the image's compression ratio or change whether or not the image is animated.